# What is the time complexity of this?

Tags: time-complexity

#### Code:

```
int main()
{
    for(long long i=0;i<10000000;i++)
    {

    }
    return 0;
}
```

I asked this because i wanted to know , Whether an empty loop add to the time of running of program. Like, say we do have a function within the loop but it does not run on every loop due to some condition:

#### Code:

```
int main()
{
    for(long long i=0;i<10000;i++)
    {
        for(long long i=1;i<10000;i++)
        {
              if(//"some condition")
              {
                func(); // some function which we know is going to run only one-hundredth of the time due to the condition. time complexity of func() is O(1).
              }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Will the timecomplexity be `O(N*N)`??

Comment: first code is O(n) constant time complexity and the 2nd is O(n^2) quadratic  time complexity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time-complexity is only meaningful in the context of variable-sized data-set; it describes how quickly the program's total execution time will increase *as the size of the data-set increases*.  For example, if you have N items to process, and your algorithm needs to read each of those items a fixed number of times, then your algorithm is considered to be O(N).

In your first case, if we assume you have a "data set" whose current size is 10000000, then your single for-loop would be O(N) -- but note that since your for-loop doesn't have any observable effects, an optimizing compiler would probably just omit the loop entirely, reducing it to effectively O(1).

In your second (nested-loop) example (assuming the variable-set-size is 10000), the algorithm is O(N^2), because the number of steps the program has to run increases with the square of the set-size.  That is true regardless of how often the internal `if` test evaluates to true, because the program will have to do some steps (such as evaluating the `if` condition) N*N times no how often (or rarely) the if-test evaluates to true.  (Again, the exception would be if the compiler could somehow prove that the `if` statement never evaluates to true, or that the `func()` function had no observable side-effects, in which case it could legally omit the whole thing and just `return 0` immediately)

Comment: I got it , thanx :)

Answer (score 0):

Your first code has a worst-case complexity of `O(n)`, because it iterates `n` times. Regardless of it doing nothing or a milllion things in each iteration, it is always of `O(n)` complexity. It may not be optimized away and the optimizer may not skip the empty loop.

Similarly, your second program has a complexity of `O(n^2)` because it iterates `n^2` many times. The `if` condition inside may or may not be satisfied for some cases, and the program may not execute in the cases where the `if` is not satisfied, but it visits `n^2` cases, which is enough to establish an `O(n^2)` complexity.

Comment: Thanx for the info :)